# elastic search, agent enrollment failure

Tags: elasticsearch, agent, fleet

I am trying to enroll agent onto my fleet server, the server is live but whenever I try to connect my agent it doesn't work.

- I keep encountering the same error:

  ```
  {"log.level":"warn","@timestamp":"2023-06-06T19:28:55.258+0100","log.logger":
  "tls","log.origin": {"file.name":"tlscommon/tls_config.go","file.line":104},"message":
  "SSL/TLS verifications disabled.","ecs.version":"1.6.0"} 
  {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-06-06T19:28:55.564+0100","log.origin":
  {"file.name":"cmd/enroll_cmd.go","file.line":478},"message":"Starting enrollment to 
  URL: https://10.0.2.15:443/","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
  {"log.level":"warn","@timestamp":"2023-06-06T19:28:55.790+0100","log.logger":"tls",
  "log.origin":{"file.name":"tlscommon/tls_config.go","file.line":104},"message":
  "SSL/TLS verifications disabled.","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
  Error: fail to enroll: fail to execute request to fleet-server: dial tcp 10.0.2.15:443: 
  connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
  For help, please see our troubleshooting guide at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/fleet/8.8/fleet-troubleshooting.html
  Error: enroll command failed with exit code: 1
  ```

I have tried to run the same commands with `--insecure` and as a admin but it doesn't work, I am running both the fleet server (kali purple) and the agent(Windows) on VMs.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using port 9200 instead of 443? 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/fleet/8.8/fleet-troubleshooting.html#:~:text=Note%3A%20Port%20443%20is%20commonly%20used%20in%20Elastic%20Cloud.%20However%2C%20with%20self%2Dmanaged%20deployments%2C%20your%20Elasticsearch%20may%20run%20on%20port%209200%20or%20something%20entirely%20different.

Comment: I believe you are trying to reach the fleet server, which usually expose the port 8220.

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

[By default the fleet-server expose the port 8220](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/fleet/current/fleet-settings.html), you may want to try the following ip:

- `https://10.0.2.15:8220`

Comment: I tried to search for that but it did not appear it shows 404 what would you advise me to do?

Comment: Show us the configuration for the fleet server

Comment: curl -L -O https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/elastic-agent/elastic-agent-8.8.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
tar xzvf elastic-agent-8.8.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
cd elastic-agent-8.8.0-linux-x86_64
sudo ./elastic-agent install \
  --fleet-server-es=https://10.0.2.15:9200 \
  --fleet-server-service-token=AAEAAWVsYXN0aWMvZmxlZXQtc2VydmVyL3Rva2VuLTE2ODYzMzUxNjk2ODQ6LXh1NmZBZUZRa21ud01SeFFiM1RHdw \
  --fleet-server-policy=fleet-server-policy \
  --fleet-server-es-ca-trusted-fingerprint=43521e7d1aed54626c69af9267f6868d50d62f224940027360f4501605ae2a93 \
  --fleet-server-port=8220

Comment: https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/kali-purple/documentation/-/blob/main/301_kali-purple/installation.txt i followed this guide exactly and restarted kibana and elastic search once right at the end,everything works besides enrolling agents as the target machine actively refuses it.

Comment: Put all this information in your question for more readability